# Parents vs Children

Tags: jquery

I have two level lists

```
<ul>
   <li></li>
   <li></li>
   <li>
      <ol>
         <li></li>
         <li class="active"></li>
         <li></li>
      </ol>
   </li>
   <li></li>
   <li></li>
</ul>
```

How i can use inner LI active class to add new class into parent LI, like

```
 <ul>
      <li class="parent">
         <ol>
           <li class="active">
```

Comment: `$('.active').parents('li:first').addClass('parent')`

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon: You should post that as an answer, it's better than any of the current ones. You might want to explain as well why you didn't use `closest` (you have a good reason, but it's easy to miss at first).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Should I? I mean, it doesnt feel right getting reputation for such an easy question... Oh well, I will.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I miss it, why not using closest()?

Comment: @A.Wolff closest li will return itself

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon Damn ya! ;) But `.closest('li:not(.active)')` would work

Comment: @A.Wolff Indeed it would. What's the best, I don't know.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon i guess using parents() seems more readable

Answer (score 5):

## Your answer

You should use :

```
$('.active').parents('li:first').addClass('parent');
```

If you want to get the first parent or :

```
$('.active').parents('li').addClass('parent');
```

If you want to get all parents.

## Why not using closest

jQuery has the `closest()` method. Usually, that's what we should use, but in this case, `.closest('li')` will return itself since **it include the current element in the check**.

However, as [A.Wolff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1414562/a-wolff) pointed out, you could use `:not()` in the selector to exclude the active one, just like that :

```
$('.active').closest('li:not(.active)').addClass('parent');
```

### More solutions

- [T.J. Crowder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157247/t-j-crowder) has other solutions in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27190466/2324107) that would work too;

Answer (score 1):

You have a few choices, but I think either of:

```
$('.active').parents('li:first').addClass('parent');

$('.active').parents('li').first().addClass('parent');
```

...would probably be simplest and clearest, with

```
$('.active').parent().closest('li').addClass('parent');
```

...coming second.

You can't just go straight to `closest` because `closest` starts with the element you're looking at, and so would return itself.

Example:

```js
$("li.active").parents("li").first().addClass("parent");
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
.parent {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<ul>
   <li>a</li>
   <li>b</li>
   <li>
      <ol>
         <li>c</li>
         <li class="active">d</li>
         <li>e</li>
      </ol>
   </li>
   <li>f</li>
   <li>g</li>
</ul>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: But I'm unable to understand why its selecting to current element with the closest that I had answered...

Comment: @Bhojendra-C-LinkNepal: Because `closest` **first** checks what's already in the set to see if they match, and only goes up to the parent if it doesn't.

Comment: Oh! I had no idea of this before. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Bhojendra-C-LinkNepal, @T.J.Crowder, it is always easier to demonstrate something with an example : http://jsfiddle.net/zf93rkpq/ Inspect the `li`.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon I've already inspected with my code, but was not understanding the fact..

Comment: @T.J.Crowder why to use .first() ?

Comment: @Bhojendra-C-LinkNepal: In case at some point they put all this inside a *third* list.

Comment: I don't think so, please see html markup however if adds something inside that list even then .first() method doesn't need

Comment: @Bhojendra-C-LinkNepal: Again: "...at some point they put **all this** inside a *third* list..." That is, taking all of the HTML above, and putting it *inside* another list. We don't want that list's `li` to be modified.

Comment: @Bhojendra-C-LinkNepal: I'm sorry if somehow the above isn't clear (although I think it is), but I've given this as much time as seems reasonable. Best,

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work.

```
$('.active').parent().parent().addClass('parent');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the given below code is the best solution as closest() will travel up in dom until it finds the match whereas the parents() will travel up upto root of the document which will be expensive.

$('.active').closest('li:not(.active)').addClass('parent');